# Density of solids and liquids composed of different isotopes

Tags: density, isotopes

In this question, I am only considering conditions fairly close to STP and moderately but not extremely high accuracy.  E.g. a quite well equipped school laboratory.

For gases, the density will be proportional to the molecular weight but this will not be so for liquids and solids.  Many factors will affect the density but if we take two isotopes of a single element e.g. $^{118}Sn$ and $^{120}Sn$ or $^{79}Br$ and $^{81}Br$, will the density be proportional to the atomic mass?

For a more complex example, how about varieties of water with different hydrogen and oxygen isotopes.

Comment: The answer is yes. Why would it not be?

Comment: I could not see a reason but I wanted to confirm that.  With the elements, it seemed very likely.  With compounds, e.g. the varieties of water, slightly less so.

Comment: Couldn't adding neutrons to the nucleus alter the valence electron orbital bonding distance?  Say, diamond form of Carbon.  If the bond length is increased by just 2%, the density would drop by nearly 10% which should be measurable under the conditions you described.

Comment: @JosephHirsch That's the sort of consideration I wanted to check.

Comment: Hydrogen gas (H2) has a density of 0.0899 g/mL, while the pure isotope version, D2, is about twice as dense, with a value of 0.169 g/mL.

Comment: @Farcher Yes, for gases, the question is simple.  I am asking about liquids and solids.

Comment: D2O Has a density of 1.107 g/ml

Comment: DCl-37 and HCl-35 have bond lengths that vary by about 6% mostly due to the difference between D and H.  https://www.odinity.com/spectra-molecular-structure-hcl-dcl/

Comment: @JosephHirsch That would seem to be my answer: the density may vary other than as predicted from the atomic masses.

Comment: The number @Farcher gave would give $D2O$ about 0.5% lower density than the mass ratio of the molecules, but that's due only to the hydrogen being an isotope.  It implies that heavy liquid hydrogen could be on the scale of 10% different,

Comment: @JosephHirsch Thanks, I was planning that calculation.  So, the evidence seems to be that we cannot predict the density of isotopic variants of liquids and solids from a knowledge of one variety and the isotopes.

Comment: I would say that we can say that adding neutrons seems to lower the density to atomic mass ratio on a scale of about 10%

Comment: @JosephHirsch For that specific case but it would not seem likely across all.  E.g. $^{235}UF_6$ and $^{238}UF_6$.

Comment: Should I have put this in Chemistry?  How can I move it?